# Set order buttons can be clicked

Tags: vb6

I have THREE buttons on a form and would like to control the order in which they can be CLICKED based on an ever changing random number made up of 3 digits
I can control the click order as long as the random number does not change
As the code is now the random number is not being generated
I just change the random number to test
I understand what is needed is a valid test when clicking the buttons looked at using an Array not much luck

**How to dynamically associate the position of the number in the String to control the buttons click order?**

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click()
  ck = 0
  GetPos
  tbOne.Text = S1
End Sub

Private Sub GetPos()
  Dim Y As Integer
  S1 = "132" 'Random Number

  For Y = 1 To Len(S1)
    pos = Mid(S1, Y, 1) 'Position of Value in S1 the Random Number
    lbOne.AddItem pos & vbNewLine
  Next
End Sub

Private Sub btnOne_Click()
  ck = ck + 1
  If Mid(S1, 1, 1) = "1" And ck = 3 Then
    btnOne.BackColor = vbYellow
  Else
  ck = 4

  If btnOne.BackColor = vbYellow Then
    Exit Sub
  End If
        
  btnOne.BackColor = vbRed

  If btnOne.BackColor <> vbYellow Then
    btnOne.Enabled = False
  End If
  End If
  End Sub

Private Sub btnTwo_Click()
  ck = ck + 1
  If Mid(S1, 2, 1) = "3" And ck = 1 Then
    btnTwo.BackColor = vbYellow
  Else
  ck = 4 ' Prevents other buttons from being Yellow

  If btnTwo.BackColor = vbYellow Then
    Exit Sub
  End If
   
  btnTwo.BackColor = vbRed
  If btnTwo.BackColor <> vbYellow Then
    btnTwo.Enabled = False
  End If
  End If
  End Sub

Private Sub btnThree_Click()
  ck = ck + 1
  If Mid(S1, 3, 1) = "2" And ck = 2 Then
    btnThree.BackColor = vbYellow
  Else
  ck = 4

  If btnThree.BackColor = vbYellow Then
    Exit Sub
  End If

  btnThree.BackColor = vbRed
  If btnThree.BackColor <> vbYellow Then
    btnThree.Enabled = False
  End If
  End If
  End Sub
```

Comment: Why was this question tagged VB.NET? I wasted my time reading a question is completely irrelevant to me. Those tags are there to tell people that the question is relevant to them. Don't use them to lure people to your questions who might not otherwise look at it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Writing the code in both variation of the language  I did not try to bate and switch people Sorry for your loss of 2 min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do what you need:

```
Private Sub btnOne_Click()
   ck = ck + 1
  
   If ck = Mid(S1, 1, 1) Then
      btnOne.BackColor = vbYellow
   Else
      btnOne.BackColor = vbRed
      btnOne.Enabled = False
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnTwo_Click()
   ck = ck + 1
  
   If ck = Mid(S1, 2, 1) Then
      btnTwo.BackColor = vbYellow
   Else
      btnTwo.BackColor = vbRed
      btnTwo.Enabled = False
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnThree_Click()
   ck = ck + 1
  
   If ck = Mid(S1, 3, 1) Then
      btnThree.BackColor = vbYellow
   Else
      btnThree.BackColor = vbRed
      btnThree.Enabled = False
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I add this below the Else ck = 4 It prevents the last value from being Yellow if the other two are Red Still trying to print he correct order to click from James_Duh code

Answer (score 0):

This code finds all the information you need
I am still trying to implement the values in the respective button clicks events

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click()
S1 = "132"
S2 = "321"
    FindPlace
    tbOne.Text = S1
End Sub

Private Sub FindPlace()

Dim Y As Integer
Dim i As Integer

tbOne.Text = S1

lbOne.Clear

For Y = 1 To Len(S2)
pos = Mid(S1, 4 - Y, 1)
S3 = Mid(S2, Y, 1)

    For i = 1 To Len(S1)
        If Mid(S1, i, 1) = S3 Then
            lbOne.AddItem "Press " & i & " the value " & pos & " is in Position " & Mid(S1, i, 1)
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks promising I might try setting the tab order to the i value and if tab order <> i then make the button vbRed Else make it vbYellow Food for Though I did this in Android Studio but don't have that machine at the present time